# Android : How to remove duplicate from CallLog?

Tags: android, duplicates, calllog

```
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            new String []{ "max(date) as max_date", "name", "date","type", "number" },
            " 1=1) group by(number ", null,
            CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

My query is wrong,

no one has done a similar query,

how to query the results did not repeat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String strGroupBy = " 1=1) group by( "+android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER;
```